# How to use PHP variable in echo?

Tags: php, echo

So, I have this PHP variable :

```
$text = 'Click on this';

echo '< a href="Google.com"> $text < /a>'
```

How do I have "Click on this" as the hyperlink text?

So far, the output is showing as $text in the HTML.

Comment: `echo '<a href="Google.com"> ', $text, '</a>';`

Comment: You arent escaping your input

Answer (score 4):

Two errors:

1. Missing semi-colon
2. Variables are *not* interpolated inside of single quotes. Either use double quotes or other ways of places variables inside of strings.

Example:

```
$text = 'Click on this';
echo "<a href=\"Google.com\"> $text </a>";
```

or

```
$text = 'Click on this';
echo '<a href="Google.com"> ', $text, ' </a>';
```

or

```
$text = 'Click on this';
echo '<a href="Google.com"> ' . $text . ' </a>';
```

or

```
$text = 'Click on this';
printf('<a href="Google.com"> %s </a>', $text);
```

Comment: what no heredoc example ? :-)

Comment: @Dagon I *knew* I was forgetting something!

Comment: I guess you don't have to escape the double quotes in the `printf`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Correct. I inadvertently left them in there.

Comment: Oh btw, I'm pretty sure `href="Google.com"` is interpreted as a relative URL, it should contain the protocol to work properly. But that's another problem altogether, and possibly it was just a placeholder for OP's MCVE. Just felt like commenting in any case.

Comment: So, is it the same concept for : echo '<option value="jl">'.$variable .'</option>';